# Sitecore language search with Lucene.NET

Tags: sitecore, lucene.net, culture

I am using Alex Shyba's Advanced Database Crawler to index data from Sitecore and Lucene.NET queries to make search queries. I have it working solidly for the most part but having issues with the _language field when I try to do a term match for example en-US, zh-CN and de-DE.

It returns all results for the 'en' culture. But for example in the zh-CN culture it's returning about 99% of the results and leaving out 2-3 articles from each set. The en and zh-CN are different versions of the same item. I can see both information about the item in both cultures in the index via Luke.

I am using TermQuery on the language field to return data. I tried using PhraseQuery and WildCardQuery but everytime I got the same results.

I tried escaping the hyphen since Standard Analyzer doesn't like hypens with a back slash but that didn't work either.

At this point I am out of ideas. How can I have my queries return all the matching documents?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ADC has its own query objects to define search parameters. Simply use the `Language` property on the [SearchParam object](http://svn.sitecore.net/AdvancedDatabaseCrawler/Branches/v2/Sitecore.SharedSource.Searcher/Parameters/SearchParam.cs) to search by a language.

Comment: I didn't realize ADC had this class. I've used Lucene.NET queries to construct my logic. Most of my code is already done at this point and I'd hate to have to re-write anything now. Any other suggestions that you might have?

Comment: I suggest you look at the code in the ADC to see how it actually handles the language filtering.

Comment: Looks like is in that same class, the `ApplyLanguageClause()` method adds a phrase query on `BuiltinFields.Language` for the iso code of the language.